# How to save button state in RecyclerView after scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Inside `onBindViewHolder` I set a different state of a button by checking if id of that product is in a specific list:

```
    ArrayList<String> compareProducts = CompareManager
                                   .getProducts(context).getProducts();
        if (compareProducts.contains(item.getId())) {
            holder.compara.setText(context.getString(R.string.icon_checked));
        }
```

But on scrolling, the checked buttons get messed up, by appearing in different locations. As I understand, when reusing the views, `RecyclerView` uses the wrong one. But why would that happen if I check by the ID of that product?

---

Update

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) { 
// setting up other data from the view
// then change button if product was added in compare before (as mentioned before)
// then set button click listener
holder.compara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
// change the button state
// and save the ID to CompareManager which saves data to SharedPreferences

//then set holder tag
 holder.itemView.setTag(item);
```

Comment: add some more code. And are you changing the list values according to the change in checkbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the view to it's default state before checking for item.getId() so if it was checked on the previous recycled view, it wouldn't re-use that and be reset to the default state.

Comment: This did the trick. Even though the button default state was set up in layout. Now it works as it should be. Thank you.

Comment: how to do that ? can you show you onbindviewholder ..??